# Looking for an article that was only available as Bell Labs Technical Memo

Tags: reference-request, time-series

I'm not even sure if this is the right place to ask and even if it is, I'm well aware it is a bit of a stretch, but anyways:

I'm looking for the article ["Asymptotic properties of robust generalized M-estimates for the first order autoregressive parameter"](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=1446566440346445219&hl=en&oi=scholarr) from 1976 (or 1977) by R.D. Martin and J. Jong (sometimes also cited as J. de Jong). The catch is that it seems to only be availabe in the form of a Bell Labs Technical Memo and I haven't been able to find it online or as physical copy anywhere. I also tried sending an email to the author I was able to find (Prof. Martin, the other author seems to have left the academic world), but unfortunately did not receive a response.

The article has 20 citations, some of them quite recent even, so I'm hoping that for some miraculous reason somebody here might be able to help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this: Snail mail to [Martin](http://www.pce.uw.edu/biography/douglas-martin/) a self-addressed and stamped (with sufficient postage) [envelope](https://www.smartpractice.com/Images/Products/PC/PhotoLg/EN0145.jpg) along with your request. Also, briefly explain why you are interested in the paper. For what it's worth, I got a photocopy (with a short personal note) of an old (early 1960s) locally published (and probably unavailable outside of Harvard University) paper from [Andrew M. Gleason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_M._Gleason) by doing something like this back in 1994 or 1995.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately I'm not even in the US and I'm afraid the introduction of oversea mail to this approach pretty much reduces the probability of succeeding to 0.

Comment: @bhz there is an article that looks what you are after: check out http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780124381506500169 if you are a student you may be able to get access via your university library, or at least make use of inter library loans.