# Find the radius of a small sphere between a wall and a larger sphere.

Tags: circles

A sphere with a radius of 8 sits in the corner, touching the floor and two walls. A smaller sphere sits between the sphere, touching the floor, the walls, and the larger sphere. What is the radius of the smaller sphere?

I tried to create the smallest cube possible that would fit a sphere with radius 8, and use the long diagonal to determine the diameter of the smaller sphere, but i'm not sure that's correct.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2644700/whats-new-in-higher-dimensions/2644740#2644740

Comment: Hint: Try drawing the 2D cross-section of these spheres with the floor below and wall on one side

Comment: Choose a coordinate system where the walls/floor intersect at origin and the volume they enclose is the first octant. The centers of the small/large ball are $(r,r,r)$ and $(8,8,8)$. What is the distance between these two centers?