# Trying to conceptualize vectors in $4$-dimensions. Is this example accurate?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I'm new to learning Linear Algebra, and I'm trying to visualize how a vector in $4$ dimensions may work.

For this, I'm imagining a Soduku puzzle. It is a grid with $3\times 3$ big squares, with each square containing a smaller grid of $3\times 3$ squares.

Could we represent individual boxes as a 4D vector, where we use two dimensions to refer to the big box, and then another two dimensions to refer to the smaller box within the big box?

For example, the top left small box would be $[0,0,0,0]$. The bottom right would be $[2,2,2,2]$.

Am I on the right track with understanding this at all?

If this is ok, could the magnitude, as a scalar, then be used to describe the contents of the box?

For example:

$$v= [0,0,0,0]$$

$$||v|| = 3$$

I know I may be way off target, and I am grateful for your patience. I just don't want to misunderstand so fundamental.

Comment: A vector in $\mathbb R^4$ is just an ordered list of four numbers. I can’t visualize it but we don’t need to. We have a nice way to picture vectors in $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb R^3$ and that is enough.

Comment: I think that's not going to be useful. Suppose you tried to use your sudoku model to understand two dimensions. How would that help you see how the geometric part of linear algebra captures the idea of lines in the plane? That said, +1 for trying different ways to understand.

Comment: @littleO I disagree slightly with your characterization.  A *vector* is not "just" an ordered list.  An ordered list of four numbers is a $4$-tuple.  When you call something a vector, you are automatically suggesting structure beyond a simple list---vectors can be added and scaled, i.e they are elements of a vector space.

Comment: You might find this interesting: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2644700/whats-new-in-higher-dimensions/2644740#2644740

Comment: @XavierHenderson Yeah, in my mind if we call an $n$-tuple a “vector” we are suggesting that we will visualize it in a certain way (at least, when $n=2$ or $n=3$) and suggesting that we might perform certain operations such as multiplying by a scalar. In other words in my mind even though it’s just an ordered $n$-tuple, calling it a “vector” gives a hint about how we should think about it and what we might do with it.

Answer (score 2):

For the purposes of linear algebra, you can get away with visualising everything as either $\mathbb R^2$ or as $\mathbb R^3$. Any intuitive geometric argument (e.g. why projection is defined the way it is) in any higher dimension $n$ can be visualised as if $n = 2$ or $3$. When you aren't visualising anything but just computing, you can treat it as a list of four numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could represent a grid like that, but I don't think its very useful. In your example, its essentially a 9x9 grid, so you only need two dimensions to specify any one square (vertical and horizontal). If you imagine a column of 9 cubes coming out of every square, you would have a 9x9x9 cube so you would need 3 dimensions to specify any one cube. We cannot imagine the 4th dimension but it is essentially the same idea, we would get a 9x9x9x9 hypercube and would need 4 dimensions to specify any one of the 4 dimensional cubes.

When dealing with higher dimensions, you have to let go and just follow the math.